# How can I generate a random alphanumeric string every 30 seconds?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'personnel_ids' with two fields: 'personnel_id' and 'personnel_random_id'.
The values in 'personnel_id' are static and never change the entire time. These values are also what links the person to their data in the other tables (addresses, contact info, etc.)

What I am trying to achieve is that the 'personnel_random_id' should be a unique, random alphanumeric (ABCDEFHGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789) string of 10 characters. This field will never be filled in "manually" and should be auto-generated. I would also like it to update on a set interval of 30 seconds such that each value in the column gets wiped and a new value inserted in its place on the interval.

I am brand new to SQL and from what I understand, I think this is a two-part issue. There should probably be a trigger for when a new value gets added to 'personnel_id' such that a new value can be assigned in 'personnel_random_id' and a CREATE EVENT on a schedule for 30 seconds. Something like the two things as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `generate_random_identifiers` BEFORE UPDATE ON `personnel_ids` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    declare ready int default 0;
    declare rnd_str text;
    if new.personnel_random_id is null then
        while not ready do
            set rnd_str := lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,6)), 10, 36), 6, 0);
            if not exists (select * from personnel_random_id where personnel_random_id = rnd_str) then
                set new.personnel_random_id = rnd_str;
                set ready := 1;
            end if;
        end while;
    end if;
END
```

and

```
CREATE EVENT assign_random
ON SCHEDULE 30 SECOND

DO...
```

Full disclosure that I pulled the trigger from another question asked on here and tried altering it to fit my needs. It doesn't throw any errors but it also doesn't seem to do anything when updating/altering/etc.

I am at a loss as to how I should implement this or if I am even on the right track. Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to reissue a new randomized id every 30 seconds? Can you not randomize it when you use it? What are you using it for?

Comment: There's a scalability problem with your approach: if you update every row of your table twice a minute, your system will get slower and slower as you add rows. Eventually you'll be unable to complete the update in thirty seconds. And, MySQL's `RAND()` isn't cryptographically secure. You might [edit] your question to explain what you need to do, or ask another question.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I suppose I could randomize it at the time it is accessed. Though I would still want the string to only be active for 30 seconds.

Comment: @O.Jones I agree it is not perfectly secure but with the number of combinations that arise from 36 choices and 10 characters would be something like 3.6 x 10^15 possible combinations. 

The general idea is that a user will be able to verify their peronnel_id without needing to expose their actual ID. With it randomizing on an interval (or even when accessed and expiring after 30 seconds), someone won't be able to randomly target or replicate someones ID in the app. It also would prevent the sharing as it is shuffling--so my friend can't use my random ID even if I sent it to them.